# log4net - is it a good practice create many loggers for tracing purposes?

Tags: c#, log4net, messaging, nservicebus

I want to add tracing capabilities to my messaging application. Each message I use has an unique identifier which is carried on to subsequent messages (messages spawned by the original message).

To be able to monitor the lifetime behavior of a message across multiple processes and potentially servers I want to use the log4net remoting appender.

I could use one logger and encode the message ID in the message itself:

- `Logger: "MessageLivetime"` `Message: "SomeId | message text")`

However I thought it would be smart if I created a logger per message:

- `Logger: "MessageLivetime.SomeId"` `Message: "message text")`

However since the `LogManager` class hast no method to remove a logger I worry about running into problems because thousands of abandoned loggers will be created.

Can someone with more insight to log4net give me a hint if this approach is viable?

I already found context properties. Are they be a better option? And how do I write to the event context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any benefit in including the ID within the logger itself. It feels the wrong way round to me.

[This tutorial](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-6-Log-Event-Context.aspx) on logging contexts may help you. Assuming everything for a single message occurs in a single thread, you can set a context property for the message ID, use an appropriate logging format, and the message ID will just appear in the logs for you.

Comment: Thanks, I settled onto context properties.